# Difference between image formats RGB888 and ARGB8888

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I'm new to image processing and game development. I was following a tutorial in which it suggest to use background image of format `RGB888`and for sprites, buttons and other rest icons it suggest to use `ARGB8888` format.

Most basic difference is there Bits `RGB888` is 24bit and `ARGB8888` is 32 bit.

So I want to know what is real difference between these two format and how they effect in visual representation?

Comment: You got the "most basic" part wrong. The basicest of basic difference is, one contains an `A` and the other not. (That means more than you seem to realize.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

More detail on the colour space on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) and more information on bitmaps on [Android Developers Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888). **A** lpha, **R** ed, **G** reen and **B** lue channels are represented. The alpha channel denotes the level of ***transparency*** in the image. The '8' in the name refers to the number of bits per channel. So RGB is 8+8+8= 24 bits, and ARGB is 8+8+8+8 = 32 bits.

Drawing in `RGB` will allow you to choose the colour of the image for either, `RGB888` assumes an alpha value of `255`. Adding the Alpha value by using `ARGB8888` will allow you to set the transparency yourself with a number between 0 (fully transparent) and 255 (fully opaque).  An example of adding transparency badly to a menu in Android would be something like the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for transparency point +1. Can you please elaborate your answer and tell me some thing more about there visual difference they can make if they are used together?

Comment: @Crawler expanded a little, just to say it's a default of 255 in RGB but in ARPG you can control it, and added a picture that clearly shows why sometimes a transparent item is a bad idea!

Answer (score 8):

`RGB888` is 24-bit, not 8-bit. Both formats you mention are 8 bits per channel, but one has three channels and one has four.

The difference is that `ARGB` adds an *alpha channel* that specifies opacity for each pixel. It's how you get semi-transparent images.

`RGB` is the same as `ARGB` with an implicit assumption that the alpha value is 255, or, in other words, fully opaque.

Answer (score 7):

**`A`** - Alpha

**`R`** - Red

**`G`** - Green

**`B`** - Blue

The difference is that `ARGB` adds an alpha channel that specifies opacity for each pixel. By using it you can get semi-transparent images/overlays.

**`RGB888`** is 24-bit, not 8-bit.
It has *Three* channels with  8 bits per channel,

**`ARGB8888`**
 It has *Four* channels with  8 bits per channel.

Alpha value is 0-255, where 0 being fully transparent and 255 being fully opaque.

[`ARGB_8888` Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888) says: *Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes. Each channel (`RGB` and alpha for translucency) is stored with 8 bits of precision (256 possible values.) This configuration is very flexible and offers the best quality. It should be used whenever possible.*